# Parsing huge XML file to form a DOM tree

Tags: java, xml, dom

I have a huge XML file (around 904Mb) and my aim is to form it into a DOM tree, using following code:

```
    org.w3c.dom.Node html  = null;

     DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
        org.w3c.dom.Document doc = builder.parse(new File("xml_file");
        html=doc.getFirstChild();

           DocumentTraversal traversal = (DocumentTraversal) doc;

        NodeIterator iterator = traversal.createNodeIterator(
          doc.getDocumentElement(), NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT, null, true);

        for (Node n = iterator.nextNode(); n != null; n = iterator.nextNode()) {
            System.out.println("Element: " + ((Element) n).getTagName());
            String tagname = ((Element) n).getTagName();

            NamedNodeMap map = ((Element)n).getAttributes();
            if(map.getLength() > 0) {

                    for(int i=0; i<map.getLength(); i++) {
                        Node node = map.item(i);
            System.out.println(node.getNodeName());

                                     }
                                                          }
```

However, because the XML file is huge, it takes like forever to create the DOM tree. Is there any particular trick for doing so?

Comment: Did you try jaxb or is it not an option?

Comment: @sgpalit I have no idea what is `jaxb`

Comment: DOM will not work. You may try saxon, a commercial solution.  A better approach may be sax, stax...

Comment: DOM is parsing and loading all it into memory. You could try use SAX for iterating through the elements, it is considered not so memory consuming.

Comment: check this site https://jaxb.java.net/guide/Dealing_with_large_documents.html

Comment: @Jayan I know that, but i was hopping if there is anyway to `partially` load the XML file and for the DOM, at each time.

Comment: @IvanBochko I know that, but i was hopping if there is anyway to partially load the XML file and for the DOM, at each time.

Comment: If you tell us some more about what you need to do with the document, we might be able to give you more specialized advice.

Comment: @lonesome:  You should try stax.

Comment: @forty-two. Ok. the document(s) is [DMOZ directory](http://rdf.dmoz.org/). All I need is to read the file and write all links (the DMOZ directory contains Web pages addresses) into a txt file and then work with it (a simple comparison with some keywords) or read the file partially and each time, compare the read part of the DMOZ with the keywords. Something like this. I do not know if I was clear or not.

Comment: @lonesome Good! If the links are identifiable by a  qualified element name or names, without regards to positional or hierarchical context, then I would recommend having a look at the  StAX API .

Comment: @forty-two yea. As far as I know, each link has a tag name and assigned to a category, for easier a retrieval. In addition, I think a link in a higher XML's tag has no logical preference(s) to one in a lower one. They are more likely are formed just alphabetically or based on the categories alphabetical orders.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [StAX Library](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/stax/using.html); StAX is an event based pull API to handle XML. StAX takes an inputStream as an argument so not the whole XML DOM will be loaded into memory and it has a small memory footprint.

[This](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/stax/why.html) page lists the reasons for using StAX and a comparison with other methods.

Answer (score 0):

In case you haven't read this paper (http://sdiwc.us/digitlib/journal_paper.php?paper=00000582.pdf)
, it  compares a number comprehensive list of XML processing libraries today. And the best option will undoubtedly be clear to you...